# Simple JSP webpage error

Tags: java, jsp

I will keep it brief.
I am trying to make a simple login page, and despite following every tutorial out there nothing seems to be working, I keep getting the following error when clicking the button...

Error:

[image: error page]

This is my first attempt with Java web development, and let me tell you, it's off to a bad start.
Here is my code:

-index.jsp:

```html
<%@taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql"%>
    <%@page language="java" contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <jsp:include page="/" />
    .
    .
    .
    <form action="Login" method="post">
      Username:  <input type="text" name="username1" size="20px"> <br>
      Password:  <input type="password" name="password1" size="20px <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
```

-servletA.java

```
public class servletA extends HttpServlet {
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String use  = request.getParameter("username1");
    String pass = request.getParameter("password1");

    response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
} }
```

-Web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>servletA</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servletA</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servletA</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servletA</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

What am I doing wrong here ?, I consider my self a 7/10 developer, I have written over 30,000 Java lines of code, but this JSP thing is very counter intuitive, I've already wasted 3 days on this simple page, I'm thinking of shifting to Rails.

Comment: Which URL you are trying to hit?

Comment: Give fully qualified name inside <servlet-class> tag then try .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace the action of the form:

```
  <form action="Login"  method="post">
```

With:

```
 <form action="servletA"  method="post">
```